# Windows-Logo-Key + Left/Right Arrow -- Keyboard shortcut equivalent on Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, windows, shortcut

I have both a mac and a PC. One simple extremely useful feature on PCs that I can't find on a mac is the shortcut `Windows+RightArrow` to maximize the active window, but only take up exactly the right half of the screen (and vice versa with `Windows+LeftArrow`).

It's extremely useful to be able to quickly do side-by-side comparisons without having to manually resize the windows, but I haven't found a similar shortcut on a mac. Does this exist for mac? Or is there a utility that allows this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) lets you set up custom keyboard shortcuts to snap windows to the left/right/top/bottom (among other things). You can also create custom gestures, and per-app gestures/shortcuts.

Comment: This link is dead, but there is a paid app here (22$ with a 45 day free trial) here: https://folivora.ai/

Answer (score 9):

If you hold down the green fullscreen button, it gives you the option to split/share the screen with a second window

Comment: This feature works in full screen mode.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using an open source app called Rectangle, https://rectangleapp.com/.
With it, you can use <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> for equivalent actions.
There are some other options to explore too.

Answer (score 1):

Since asking this question many years ago, I eventually stumbled onto Spectacle https://www.spectacleapp.com/. Comes with window management out of the box with similar keyboard shortcuts (not exact, but actually more expressive than those built into Windows)

Highly recommend this for people looking to do window management on a Mac the same way you can on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally using [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) to accomplish this task which allows many keyboard shortcuts - among them is the ability to do this with Ctrl+Option+Command+Left/Right

Answer (score 0):

I use [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) for this, which allows you to set arbitrary hotkeys for all of the following functions (and more):

[image: SizeUp example]

Answer (score 0):

Another app which allows this is Magnet (https://magnet.crowdcafe.com/)

re: Prajwal's answer. There is a downside to the Mac-native approach to tiling two windows, which is that they're treated as a mac fullscreen space, with the advantages and disadvantages that entails. I prefer the addon app approach, personally.