WIN + SHIFT + RIGHT/LEFT arrow alternative for Mac with multiscreen setup
In Windows when I used multiple screens connected to my laptop, I loved a feature Win + Shift + Right/Left arrow to send tabs/windows to other monitors, is there something like that for macOS?

Have you tried any of the apps linked here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187345/windows-logo-key-left-right-arrow-keyboard-shortcut-equivalent-on-mac

I'm not aware of a macOS native option for this. I use Moom but there are a number of window management apps available, both free and paid, which enable such functionality.
